# Solving error "Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.0 does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, project.json

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 complete application running using `net461` references. Now I am trying to add another framework - `netcoreapp1.0`. For this, I have updated my project.json like this:

```
{
   "userSecretsId":"",
   "version":"2.4.0-*",
   "buildOptions":{
      "emitEntryPoint":true,
      "preserveCompilationContext":true
   },
   "dependencies":{
      "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug":"1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader":"14.0.0",
      "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc":"1.0.0-preview2-final"
   },
   "tools":{
      "BundlerMinifier.Core":"2.0.238",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools":"1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools":"1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools":"1.0.0-preview2-final"
   },
   "commands":{
      "ef":"EntityFramework.Commands",
      "web":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel"
   },
   "frameworks":{
      "net461":{

      },
      "netcoreapp1.0":{
         "imports":[
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
         ]
      }
   },
   "runtimes":{
      "win10-x64":{

      },
      "win81-x64":{

      },
      "win8-x64":{

      },
      "win7-x64":{

      }
   },
   "publishOptions":{
      "exclude":[
         "**.user",
         "**.vspscc",
         "wwwroot",
         "node_modules"
      ]
   },
   "scripts":{
      "prepublish":[
         "npm install",
         "bower install",
         "gulp clean",
         "gulp min"
      ]
   }
}
```

After modifying project.json, I got this error:

> Failed to make the following project runnable: MVC6_Full_Version
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) reason: Expected coreclr library not found
>   in package graph. Please try running dotnet restore again.

To resolve this, I ran `dotnet restore` command but no luck.

Then, I added this block:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

After adding this block, I got a different error:

> Code: NU1002 Description: The dependency Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.0
>   does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.

Basically, I want to add both references in my applications - .NET Framework 4.6.1 and ASP.NET Core 1.0.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You can take a look at my answer, hopefully it will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420980/6535426

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's definitely possible to build ASP.NET Core projects using .NET Framework or .NET Core. You're really close - just a few tweaks needed:

- Remove the `runtimes` section, unless you are intending to do native compilation (somewhat unusual)
- Place the reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in a `dependencies` section *inside* the `netcoreapp1.0` section. I've tested the following change and it restores and compiles without errors:

**project.json**

```
...

   "frameworks": {
      "net461": {

      },
      "netcoreapp1.0": {
         "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
               "type": "platform",
               "version": "1.0.0"
            }
         },
         "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
         ]
      }
   }
```

The `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency is only required for .NET Core, and adding it here will make sure it's available when building for that framework.

Also, the `commands` section has been deprecated and can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I referenced .net core class library in .net 4.6.1 by changing the following.

Before I was getting this error when trying to reference the .net core from .net 4.6.1
[image]

Fix:

Original

```
    {
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Interop.SHDocVw.dll": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.mshtml.dll": "7.0.3300.1"
    },

    "frameworks": {
    //"net461": {},
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "net461"
      ]
    }
   },

    "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ]
    }
   }
```

Corrected

```
    {
     "dependencies": {
        "Interop.SHDocVw.dll": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.mshtml.dll": "7.0.3300.1"
     },

    "frameworks": {
        "net461": {
        },
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "type": "platform",
            "version": "1.0.0"
            }
        },
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8",
            "net461"
        ]
        }
    },

    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This project.config whoopla is a mess.  So what they mean by .NetCore, you still have to reference everything correctly, not as an assembly but a package.  If you expand the References -> .NetCoreApp, Version=v1.0 in a .net core app and then expand Microsoft.NetCore.App (1.0.0)....look at all those dependencies there.  So its really not a single "Core" assembly.  Its a Core that is wrapped around older assebmlies.  I don't really see the benifits of this, it does make your app lighter...but still its not a true Core.