# Adding net462 library in .net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I was able to configure .net462 into asp.net core project based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572255/solving-error-microsoft-netcore-app-1-0-0-does-not-support-framework-netframew/38778548) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/06/16/asp-net-core-rc2-error-nu1002-the-dependency-system-runtime-loader-4-0-0-rc2-24027-does-not-support-framework-netframeworkversionv4-6-1/)

But  now I want to reference a library that was developed in .net 4.6.2. When I add that project as `net462` framework dependency I get error

> The dependency `MyLibrary` could not be resolved

This is my entire project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    },
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyLibrary": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Note that I'm adding `MyLibrary` dependency for `.net462` framework not as global dependency

Comment: If your `MyLibrary` is a csproj, not a project.json/xproj, this isn't going to work.

Comment: The easy solution is to package it up as a NuGet package and reference it without `target: project`.